# Prevent accidental scrolling with swipe in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile. When swiping left or right the user can accidentally scroll the page, frequently "bouncing" the page off the top of the window. I want to suppress page scrolling during the left or right swipe event. I've tried:

```
$('#foo').on('swipeleft swiperight', function (ev) {
    $.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold = 100;
    ...
});
```

but this does not prevent the behavior. I also tried adding `position: fixed` during the swipe event for both the html and body DOMs. Neither works because they alter the flow of the page. How should I approach this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You should add that line in `mobileinit`. `$(document).on("mobileinit", function () { $.event..... });`. Call it after jQuery.js and before jQM.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a debounce function like the one I took from [here](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

```
// Minified: only 160 bytes!
function debounce(a,b,c){var d;return function(){var e=this,f=arguments;clearTimeout(d),d=setTimeout(function(){d=null,c||a.apply(e,f)},b),c&&!d&&a.apply(e,f)}}

var myDebouncedFn = debounce(function() {
 // All the taxing stuff you do
}, 250);
window.addEventListener('swipe', myDebouncedFn);
```

But you should **better read into [jQuery Mobile Documentation](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/)**, because this is built in:

```
$.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold (default: 10px) – More than this horizontal displacement, and we will suppress scrolling.
$.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold (default: 1000ms) – More time than this, and it isn't a swipe.
$.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold (default: 30px) – Swipe horizontal displacement must be more than this.
$.event.special.swipe.verticalDistanceThreshold (default: 75px) – Swipe vertical displacement must be less than this.
```

Answer (score 1):

With Beta 2 they have released some additional swipe functionality

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

> **Configurable swipe event thresholds added**
>
> There were a number of hard-coded constants in the
>   jquery.mobile.event.js swipe code. For developers who need to tweak
>   those constants  to allow a greater vertical displacement and still
>   register a swipe, this new feature allows them to be adjusted. Thanks
>   to mlitwin for contributing this.
>
> - scrollSupressionThreshold (default: 10px) – More than this horizontal
>     displacement, and we will suppress scrolling
> - durationThreshold (default: 1000ms) – More time than this, and it isn’t a swipe
> - horizontalDistanceThreshold (default: 30px) – Swipe horizontal
>     displacement must be more than this.
> - verticalDistanceThreshold (default: 75px) – Swipe vertical displacement must be less than this.